# How do i Create Appointment in EWS with Timezone ignored

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How do i Create Appointment  in EWS with Timezone ignored

Im using EWS to Create an Appointment but when the user sees the appointment the time is off by 3 hours.

How do I get Excahgne to take whatever time i give it and assume its in the users timezone?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore timezones, but if you do not define the timezone it will use UTC.
To use the Exchange Service Timezone, do the below:

```cs
Appointment a = new Appointment(Service);

// If using Exchange 2007 SP1
a.StartTimeZone = Service.TimeZone;

// If using Exchange 2010 or Higher
a.StartTimeZone = Service.TimeZone;
a.EndTimeZone = Service.TimeZone;
```

To use the timezone of the local computer, use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`

```cs
Appointment a = new Appointment(Service);

// If using Exchange 2007 SP1
a.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

// If using Exchange 2010 or Higher
a.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
a.EndTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
```

Comment: there is no way to use that accounts default timezone?

Comment: @Rico: Does an account definitely *have* a default time zone?

Comment: I don't know. But i simply need that time to upload into exchange and assume the timezone of the client

Comment: Adjusted my original answer, I hope that answer's your question.